# Why I don't create all the pieces?

Tags: c#, foreach, parallel-processing, task, parallel.foreach

I have this code:

```
List<Piezas> lstPiezasNuevas = new List<Piezas>();
Parallel.ForEach(lstNodosDB, iteradorEstructuraPlantilla =>
{
    lstPiezasNuevas.Add(new Piezas()
    {
        FechaEstado = miFechaEstado,
        HorasParcialesFallos = 0,
        HorasParcialesFuncionamiento = 0,
        HorasTotalesFallos = 0,
        HorasTotalesFuncionamiento = 0,
        IDComponente = iteradorEstructuraPlantilla.IDComponente,

        //El estado por defecto al crear una pieza será no instalada.
        IDEstado = 5,

        NumeroSerie = null
    });
});

dbContext.Piezas.AddRange(lstPiezasNuevas);
```

lstNodosDB has 864 items, I take it from the database. I want to crete one piece for each node, so I would like to use e parallel.foreach.

I use a auxiliar list, lstPiezasNuevas because if in the parallel.Foreach I try to add the new piece to the dbContext.Piezas I get an exception that it says that the collection it was modified. So I use an auxiliar list.

But the problem is that when I finish the parallel.Forach lstPiezasNuevas has only 813 items, but I would have 864. If I execute the method many times sometimes I only have 805 and in other cases can be different, but I don't have the security of that I always get all the items.

Why? If I am not wrong, parallel.Foerach process all the items of the source list, and I would have all the pieces. But it is not the case.

In my probes, I can notice better performance against the normal foreach, so I would like to try to solve this problem with parallel.foreach.

Comment: Please make more of an effort to format your code nicely in future - there was no reason for it to be so far over. Also be aware that `List<T>` isn't thread-safe, so that may well be part of your problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [concurrent collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) (.NET 4). `List<T>` is not thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks, I use System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection and it works fine. Thanks so much.